# Passing an array to another page through vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am currently trying to pass an array thats accessible on one page to the next.
The next page is accessed on a forms submission using this.$router.push('path')

Is there any way for me to pass the array over as well when submitting the form so that I can access it on the new page?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45151810/passing-props-with-programmatic-navigation-vue-js

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that with Vue router directly as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69066002/8816585), you can only pass `String` type.

If you want to access it on another page, you can either:

- store it in cookies or localStorage (not recommended)
- fetch it from the submission: the backend probably gives you a response
- use Vuex or even some state that can overlap between the current and next page

Comment: Is there anyway to pass a string but not have it visible in the URL?

Comment: All of the 3 methods above do not use the URL (the state is invisible for the end user). If you `POST` something, you can send a body yeah, but this is unrelated to what you're trying to achieve here. I mean, it is somehow related to my 2nd solution but still not directly what you're asking for here. @blue4euro4

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wanna use vuex or other store managers then the simplest way could be doing

```
this.$router.push('path').then(() => { this.$route.params.yourArray = ['value'] })
```

and then in the destination component use that same

```
this.$route.params.yourArray
```